# Cinnamon (Petra) crashed. Opens in fallback mode

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, desktop, cinnamon

I'm not an expert on linux. My cinnamon (petra) just started to chrash on logons and I have no opinion for what did I do wrong. I have found a set of errors on my .xsession-errors. The below one is the first of a set.

```
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:attila being added to access control list
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc/gpg:0:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc/ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-9rBZgc/gpg:0:1
=== xinerama setup Configuration ===
  Clone: false
  Output: Dizüstü attached to LVDS1
     status: on
     width: 1366
     height: 768
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DP1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to VIRTUAL1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
=== auto-configure - xinerama mode Configuration ===
  Clone: false
  Output: Dizüstü attached to LVDS1
     status: on
     width: 1366
     height: 768
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DP1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to VIRTUAL1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
=== Applying Configuration Configuration ===
  Clone: false
  Output: Dizüstü attached to LVDS1
     status: on
     width: 1366
     height: 768
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DP1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to VIRTUAL1
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1

(cinnamon:4650): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'cinnamon' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 141 error_code 1 request_code 153 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion 'accelerator != NULL'     failed

** (gnome-panel:4654): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'

Starting Dropbox...Initializing nemo-dropbox 2.0.1
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accelerator_parse_with_keycode: assertion 'accelerator != NULL'     failed

** (gnome-panel:4654): WARNING **: Unable to parse mouse modifier '(null)'


(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -1     and height 24

(gnome-panel:4654): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0'     failed
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
Done!

(nemo:4668): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'NemoDropbox::move' to action group     'DirExtensionsMenuGroup'

(nemo:4668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_get_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

(nemo:4668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_get_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

(nemo:4668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_ui_manager_add_ui: assertion 'name != NULL || type ==     GTK_UI_MANAGER_SEPARATOR' failed

(nemo:4668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_get_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

(nemo:4668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_get_name: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed

(nemo:4668): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_ui_manager_add_ui: assertion 'name != NULL || type == GTK_UI_MANAGER_SEPARATOR' failed
```